# Angular UI resolve function parameter undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm displaying a modal from Angular UI bootstrap

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

When clicked, a "category" parameter is passed in, however it is only defined in category, not parents.

```
$scope.addEditCategory = function(category) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: ...,
        resolve: {
            category: function() {
                //category is defined here
            },
            parents: function() {
                //category is undefined here
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, category, parents) {
            ...
        },
    });

}
```

It's even weirder if I rename the parameter to something else, then it's not defined in category or parents. My current workaround is to just define `$scope.category = category;` before declaring modalInstance and refer to it that way. I think there's some scoping issues I'm not understanding.

Comment: I should have specified Angular UI bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this ? It should be easier this way